# Is the Developer Access a Paid Service?

Tags: ringcentral

I've been working on a program to help a friend of mine annotate incoming faxes and send the annotated version back to the original sender. I research a bit and found the RingCentral Developer website and singed her up in order to register the app and get the appKey and appSecret and to get access to a sandbox. I was able to do and so far the API is very simple and easy to use, so I definitely want to go this route, however looking through the Admin Portal I the following under Service Plan:

---

Service Plan:
RingCentral Sandbox Office 4 lines Enterprise Edition

Billing Plan:
$109.98 for 1 month

Account Credit:
$0.00

Billing Cycle:
03/13/2017 - 04/12/2017

Next Billing Date:
04/13/2017

---

Is this correct? Is she going to get charge now every month in order to have access to the site?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no charge for the RingCentral Sandbox account:

- login at https://service.devtest.ringcentral.com

The RingCentral "Sandbox" tier is a free tier for development purposes. I have verified what you mentioned and will report it as an error to the team to be fixed in the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Since developer account is free and only used for development , whatever happened may be some bugs.. You can always create a support ticket to solve the issue..
Also you can mail to devsupport@ringcentral.com with the screenshots to fix that